# How to get the type of T from another type of T (ex:<ICollection<test11>>)

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

How to get the type of T from another type of T (ex:<ICollection>)?

```
 public class test11
 {
      public string Search { get; set; }
      public List<test22> Content { get; set; }
 }
 public class test22
 {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class TodoService
 {
      var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<test11>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                           
 }
 protected virtual async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ObjectResponseResult<T>> ReadObjectResponseAsync<T>()
 {
      Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
      var x = "{'search':'t','content':[{'id':'2cdc66f1-0000-0000-39ac-233c00000000'}]}"
      var typedBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(x);
     .....
 }
```

PS: My purpose is to get the class of "test11" but unfortunately I got the "ICollection" so how can I get the "test1"(type name)

[image]

Comment: Personally, I'd probably just fix the JSON by adding `[` and `]` in the case that `T` is an `ICollection` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `T` is `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<test11>`. Given a type object, you would just call `GetGenericArguments()` to get the type parameters from the generic type.

```
var type = typeParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // typeof(test11)
```

Note that you have the runtime type, here so you cannot use the generic overload of `DeserializeObject()`, you'll need to use the overload that accepts the type.

Comment: Jeff Thanks for your help, can you help me to give me an example to fix this issue.

Comment: @Willie What exactly do you think the code above is, if not an example?

Comment: @Llama  how to fix this " var typedBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(x);＂, like Jeff said I have to use the overload that accepts the type. my question is how to do it please give me an example.thanks

Comment: Do you mean you're unable to look at the overloads available to you using Intellisens, and that you're also unable to [refer to the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm)? The `DeserializeObject(String, Type)` method listed in the documentation seems to scream out "I take JSON and deserialize it to this specific type".